# Moscow State Oral Exam

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I have heard that during the 1960s, prospective students had to take an 'Oral Maths' exam (alongside written maths, physics and Russian literature).

I having trouble imagining what type of exam this would have been (more problem solving or merely reciting proofs?) and why anybody thought this would be a good idea or a useful indication of potential?

Was the exam purely oral, as in the candidates were given a problem they had to solve without any written work and on the spot? Or was it of a different format?

I assume it was scrapped but I am not sure when either.

Information on the internet is sparse so I thought I'd ask here, maybe some people even have first hand accounts.

Comment: In France, competitive exams to the best engineering schools etc also require you to have mathematics, physics and chemistry exams. In the maths one, you are usually given some questions and have about 30 minutes to prepare before having to show on a black board what you have done, and do your best to do what the jury tells you to do.

Comment: See also [this piece](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1556) about especially difficult problems reserved for Jewish applicants.

Comment: Oral exams, administered by a faculty committee, go back to the medieval period when universities were operated by Church monasteries: they were used to examine students about to enter their vocation to be sure that they had come to understand the points of accepted theology correctly (and could give proper doctrinal arguments for canonical beliefs and against heretical ones).  When universities became more secular, the practice carried over, but is now generally given only to candidates for doctoral degrees.

Comment: @vadim123 From the '90s on, there have been an increasing number of published accounts concerning this.  (Here's one I've read:  https://books.google.com/books?id=ho6fMF8ehogC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=soviet+jews+mathematics+exams&source=bl&ots=W-h_FfvWam&sig=GRURheMpU2CxxiguEj-EUg-AWJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tE_BVPqbGsKlNrTNgogF&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=soviet%20jews%20mathematics%20exams&f=false ).  Certainly, the examination system, for both written and oral exams, is open to abuse by jurors and departments, and not just in the former Soviet Union.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, how so many answers are concentrated on "Jewish problems."

The idea behind the oral exam, which was used in USSR in the places with advanced mathematical education, to understand how good the student will be able to appreciate the real mathematics. The exam was always administered after the written exam. The main point is that it is impossible to cheat at such exam, and it is simply impossible to memorize the material to convince the examiner that you actually understand math.

The structure is as follows: The student picks a random "ticket" with two theoretical questions and one problem. Then he/she is given some time to prepare. And after it the student has to present his solutions to the examiner.

There is a very nice Russian book by [Tkachuk](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7324001/) (I link a Russian text) about preparation to entrance exams with examples and general discussion. I am not sure though that it was translated into English.

Here is an example of a question: We have a quadrangle, which has all four sides equal. Does it mean that it is a rombus?

Comment: About the question here are my thoughts, there doesn't seem a lot to it: No, if you count self intersecting sides, yes otherwise. Next one proves all rhombi are convex. This seems  quite simple, opposite angles are equal for a quadrilateral. Since for a concave quadrilateral you need one angle greater than $\pi$ then as opposite angles are equal you have all angles adding up to more than $2\pi$. Then we shows that all quadrilaterals with 4 sides equal are convex. This is done by splitting the quadrilateral ABCD into two SSS congruent triangles ABD and CBD.

Comment: As angles BCD and BAD are equal, but A and C cannot be collinear, they must straddle BD and thus the shape is convex. Have I wrongly assumed something? This question seems rather straight forward.

Comment: @GridleyQuayle No one said that the figure is flat :) This is one of the "trick" questions.

Comment: @Arterm A triangular based pyramid then would be an example? I thought quadrilateral and quadrangle were synonymous but I guess not? Quite a 'twist' in the question, I can imagine how students would be upset. How does one comprehensively answer, surely there aren't 4D quadrangles too? At least I hope not (can't imagine what geometric construction that would be).

Comment: The supposed answer is 'No', because it is possible to easily make a quadrangle in 3D space, which is not rombus. But this is, of course, not a standard question. The book I linked (and its file can be easily found in the Internet) has a lot more problems from oral exam, some of which are easy to understand even if you do not know Russian. It starts on page 823.

Comment: I am still confused about 'sides'. Even if this was a 'trick' question there must be justification for the answer. Do 'sides' mean faces or edges in 3D? If faces, then the only construction I can think of in 3D that satisfies 4 angles, 4 equal sides/faces is a tetrahedron. What other construction could there be? I recognise one counter-example is enough to disprove the statement but I am still curious as to whether there are more and what they are.

Comment: This may be my translation. The problem is asking about the figure with four edges and with four corners such that all the edges have equal length.

Answer (score 0):

The role of oral exams in allowing examiners to accept/dismiss university candidates on the basis of their prejudices has already been mentioned in the comments.  You can [read this](http://www.academia.edu/1050101/Kerosinka_An_episode_in_the_history_of_Soviet_mathematics) for a further discussion of this practice.

Comment: This is a very strange answer, especially given the fact that the oral exams were a normal practice in USSR, and only one or two departments are famous with acceptance/dismissal on the basis of their prejudices.

Comment: @Artem: the "one or two" departments were usually the top-tier schools.

Comment: @AlexR. And what?

Comment: @Artem: considering you were essentially guaranteed a "coffin" exam if your last name was undesirable, I fail to see why this doesn't paint an accurate picture of oral exams at the time, for the many undesirables who applied.

Comment: @Artem: One aspect of the question is why people thought oral exams were a good idea.  The role of these exams in discriminating against (sometimes extremely strong) Jewish students is well-known, and in fact probably the best-known aspect of these exams outside the former Eastern bloc.   It may not have been the only role, or the primary role, of these exams, but it certainly seems to have been *one* of their roles.  Hopefully those with additional knowledge of these exams (you, perhaps?) can give answers explaining more about them.

Comment: @AlexR. You are mixing two different things. Oral exams were not introduced to dismiss unwanted. They were simply used for this purpose. It there were not oral exams, something else was found. For instance, there are no oral exams in US system. But please look up about asian students admission.

Comment: @Artem: you're right, it's not a reason to introduce them. It just paints one picture of what they were like though.

Comment: @AlexR. An extremely screwed picture, I would, as a witness of actual oral exam, add.

Comment: Oral exams have a long history, before any role in "affirmative action" to stabilize ethnic percentages. I agree that it is strange that there is such a focus on this ethnic angle, interesting footnote as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on some research on implementation of oral assessment in mathematics classroom, and I was wondering are there any questions/problems/concepts in mathematics that can be only assessed through Oral Examination (or types of questions where oral assessment would be more sufficient than written)?

Comment: In order to get feedback, you should pose this as a new question, and not as an answer to another question.

Answer (score -1):

In the former Soviet Union MIR Publishing helped to develop a number of books to aid in the study of such exams. Most of these books are now public domain. An example of one can be found here. http://mirtitles.org/2013/11/22/problems-in-higher-mathematics-minorsky/
These MIR problem books can be found for various technical subjects and are useful study aids.

Comment: Are all these problems from the oral exam specifically? Do you know the exact format of the exam?

Comment: I can't speak to the format of the exams or there precise content. I became aware of these books some years ago through an eastern european college.

Comment: This book has *nothing* to do with oral exams.